# How to use updatepolicy in gradle build

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I want to use `updatePolicy` for

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

with "never" in my Gradle script.

How to use `updatePolicy` with never update?

Comment: What is `updatePolicy`?

Comment: the ability to do not fetch/find updates on remonte repository when a dependency is already in cache. I looking for this configuration too.